# accessing array elements throug pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a paint program and i create an array of figures in a class
and i want to pass that array to another class and loop through it's elements
i dont understand the problem 
the main class:

```
     CFigure* FigureList[Figcount];
     CFigure* getfiglist()
     {
      return *FigureList;
      }`
```

and the other class include:

```
   CFigure *P=pManager->Getfiglist();
   for(int i=0;i<pManager->Getfigcount;i++)
    {
    *(p+i)->resize(factor); //displays error : operand of * must be a pointer
     }
```

how should i access the array elements using the passed pointer and what did i do here that caused the error . thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `*` .

Comment: @Sniper as in (p+i) ?? i tried that it cannot access any element except the first element

Comment: @Dan what difference would it make ??

Comment: Do you want an array of pointers to `CFigure` (which you currently do) or a pointer to an array of `CFigure`? And why do you need pointers here?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Comment: Where are the definitions of `p` and `pManager` and `pManager->Getfiglist()`? Create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to say about arrays in C++, here is some information that might help :

## Native C++ arrays

if you create an array like so :

```
int array[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

And you try to print the values of `array`, `&array` or `&array[0]` you will notice they are all the same values. This value is the adress of the first element in your array. There is no such thing as an array pointer, there is just a pointer to the first element.

As the other elements of your array follow the first, you can access them by adding 1 to the address of the first element (`array+1`) :

```
void print(int *array, int length)
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<length ; i++){
        cout << *(array+i) << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    print(array, 10);
}
```

It turns out that you can also use the regular expression to access your array elements and it will work fine :

```
void print(int *array, int length)
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<length ; i++){
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

## Vectors

That being said, if one is not careful with native arrays, the code may quickly get very nasty and hard to read... This is why you should use `std::vector` instead as suggested by @Ðаn.

Vectors have the particularity to be dynamic so you don't have to specify any size when you create them, and you can add as many elements as you want without caring about any pointer or memory stuff.

```
void print(vector<int> &v)
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<v.size() ; i++){
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(11);
    v.push_back(12);

    print(v);
}
```

## Links

You can read more about vectors [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

I didn't talk about it but there is also [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

Comment: You can have a pointer to an array which is different from a pointer to the first element of an array. However a pointer to an array is indistinguishable from a pointer to the first element (an array itself) of an array of arrays.